# How to remove an Integer Number from a Linked List in Java with an unkown index

Tags: java, linked-list

I do have a `LinkedList` with integer numbers 1-9

I would like to remove a specific number - say 7 - but can't be sure if it still has the index 6.

So I can't use `LinkedList.remove(int index)` - since the index might have change - but I also don't know how to cast the value into an `Object` so that I can use `LinkedList.remove(Object o)`

(I tried with `toString()` but surprisingly that didn't worked :-)

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedList<Integer> listContent = 
                  new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9));

    LinkedList<Integer> candidateList = new LinkedList<Integer>(listContent);
    int value = 7;
    String valueString = Integer.toString(value);
    candidateList.remove(valueString);
    System.out.println(candidateList);
    candidateList.remove(value);
    System.out.println(candidateList);
}
}
```

my output here is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the value in an object

```
candidateList.remove(new Integer(value));
```